# Resetting the iterator in a for...in loop

Tags: javascript, iterator, continue, for-in-loop

This is part of the code I am using to draw some random circles:

```
if(circles.length != 0) { //1+ circles have already been drawn
  x = genX(radius);
  y = genY(radius);
  var i = 0;
  iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:
  for(i in circles) {
    var thisCircle = circles[i];
    if(Math.abs(x-thisCircle["x"])+Math.abs(y-thisCircle["y"])>radius*2) {
      //overlaps
    } else {
      //overlaps
      x = genX(radius);
      y = genY(radius);
      continue iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName;
    }

    if(i == circles.length - 1) { //Last iteration
      //Draw circle, add to array
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when there is an overlap, the circle with the newly generated coordinates is not checked for overlap with the circles that the overlapping circle had already been checked with. I have tried setting i to 0 before using the continue statement but that did not work. Please help, I am really confused.

Comment: can yuo create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this?

Comment: Okay... http://jsfiddle.net/evQ8a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You should not use `for ... in` on arrays.](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#array.general)

Use `for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; ++i)` instead. Then you can reset by setting `i = 0`.

Comment: I'm trying to find that excellent site that explained a lot of JavaScript foibles, including why you shouldn't use `for ... in` on arrays... I think it was blue background, white text, with a nice sidebar table of contents... if anyone finds it before me, comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a standard for loop

```
for (var i=0,l = circles.length;i < l; i++) {
   ....  

   if (i === l) {
     // draw
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding the question, but I do not believe you can reset the iterations of a `for..in`.  You'll need to go to a `for(var i=0;...;i++)`.